# django autocomplete_fields doesn't work in TabularInline (but works in StackedInline)

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to use autocomplete-fields in TabularInine

Below my code :

```
class PersonInstitutionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    autocomplete_fields = ['institution']
    model = PersonInstitution
    extra = 0
```

When rendering the dropdown is simply empty with no error (javacsript or python)

If I use the same with StackedInline it works correctly

While checking the templates, I'm suspecting that it has to with the fact that stacked.html uses  `{% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}` but tabular.html uses `{{ field.field }}`

Also on another note, if I try to use django-autocomplete-light form in any inline

```
inlines.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at inlines.js:20
    at inlines.js:298
```

with in python the error

```
MediaOrderConflictWarning: Detected duplicate Media files in an opposite order:
admin/js/autocomplete.js
admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js
  MediaOrderConflictWarning,
```

I'm using Django version 2.1.7

Anyone had a similar issue or is there a fix for it ?

Currently the workaround I'm using is StackedInline, and putting them all in the same fieldset...but i think there should be a better solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: The `django-autocomplete-light ` is probably b/c it cant find jquery. Did you try to manually load jquery?

Comment: This works for me in Django 2.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `django-autocomplete-light` lib
https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

> ```
> from dal import autocomplete
>
> from django import forms
>
>
> class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Person
>         fields = ('__all__')
>         widgets = {
>             'birth_country': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete')
>         }
> ```
>
> Using autocompletes in the admin We can make `ModelAdmin` to use our
> form, ie:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib import admin
>
> from your_person_app.models import Person
> from your_person_app.forms import PersonForm
>
>
> class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     form = PersonForm
>
> admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
> ```
>
> Note that this also works with inlines, ie:
>
> ```
> class PersonInline(admin.TabularInline):
>     model = Person
>     form = PersonForm
> ```